# How to insert json array data to google app spreadsheet using app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two methods one method returns the data in form of JSON array. Now I want to write this data to google app script.How to do that?

Using the code below I get

> Cannot convert Array to Object" Error

```
var noEpicListArray = new Array();

if(epicCount==0){
  var noEpicMetric = {
    "issueKey": "No Epic",
    "issueSummary": "NA",
    "epicEfficiency": "NA",
    "teamName": "NA",
    "firstPassInd": "NA",
    "secondPassInd": "NA",
    "thirdPassInd": "NA",
    "tooManyPassInd": "NA",
    "storyCountInsideEpic": "NA" 
}

noEpicListArray.push(noEpicMetric);
epicWiseEpicEfficiencySheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 9).setValues(noEpicListArray); }
```

Comment: Any data being written to a Google spreadsheet (that is more than 1 cell) must first be in a 2D array.  Each inner array represents one row, each element of each inner array represents a cell in the row.  First, put your JSON data into a 2D array, then use the `setValues()` method.  JSON can be structured in many different ways, and you have not shown an example of your JSON.

Comment: @SandyGood: my JSON is   var noEpicMetric = {
        "issueKey": "No Epic For This Sprint",
        "issueSummary": "NA",
        "epicEfficiency": "NA",
        "teamName": "NA",
        "firstPassInd": "NA",
        "secondPassInd": "NA",
        "thirdPassInd": "NA",
        "tooManyPassInd": "NA",
        "storyCountInsideEpic": "NA"
      }

Answer (score 0):

To append the values from the data object to a spreadsheet, extract the value from each key/value element in the data object, put those values into an array, and append the data to the end of the existing data.  A JavaScript data object has the structure of `{"key":"value"}`

```
function dataObjectToSpreadsheet(dataObject) {
  var dataArray,k,ss,sh;//define variables without assigning a value

  dataObject= {
    "issueKey": "No Epic For This Sprint",
    "issueSummary": "NA",
    "epicEfficiency": "NA",
    "teamName": "NA",
    "firstPassInd": "NA",
    "secondPassInd": "NA",
    "thirdPassInd": "NA",
    "tooManyPassInd": "NA",
    "storyCountInsideEpic": "NA" 
    } 

  if (typeof dataObject === 'string') {//If the object was stringified
    dataObject = JSON.parse(dataObject);//convert from string to object
  }

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheeet();
  sh = ss.getSheetByName('Put sheet tab name here');

  innerArray = [];//assign an empty array to the variable innerArray

  for (k in dataObject) {//Loop through all elements of the data object
    thisValue = dataObject[k];
    dataArray.push(thisValue);
  }

  sh.appendRow(dataArray);  
}
```

Comment: actually, I was trying in below way but got "Cannot convert Array to Object" Error  var noEpicListArray = new Array();
    
  if(epicCount==0){
   var noEpicMetric = {
        "issueKey": "No Epic",
        "issueSummary": "NA",
        "epicEfficiency": "NA",
        "teamName": "NA",
        "firstPassInd": "NA",
        "secondPassInd": "NA",
        "thirdPassInd": "NA",
        "tooManyPassInd": "NA",
        "storyCountInsideEpic": "NA"
      }
   noEpicListArray.push(noEpicMetric);
   epicWiseEpicEfficiencySheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 9).setValues(noEpicListArray);
  
  }

Comment: it is writing the data in json   {epicEfficiency=NA, teamName=NA, tooManyPassInd=NA, secondPassInd=NA, issueKey=No Epic For This Sprint, storyCountInsideEpic=NA, firstPassInd=NA, issueSummary=NA, thirdPassInd=NA}